# @Lazy vs "BeanFactoryPostProcessor" Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am not good at English. And I'm a "Spring Boot" beginner. Please understand.

https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/14/lazy-initialization-in-spring-boot-2-2#enabling-lazy-initialization

I have a question in this article.

In the writing... 
"It's possible to enable laser initialization in any version of Spring Boot if you're getting your hands dirty and write a BeanFactoryPostProcessor. "

I would like to know what the difference is to use the "Lazy Annotation."

1. Using "@Lazy Annotation"
2. "...dirty and write a BeanFactoryPostProcessor. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to configure certain beans to be lazy initialised , you can annotate those beans using `@Lazy`.It is convenient but rather static. It cannot handle the cases that if you want to have more dynamic behaviour to configure some beans to be lazy based on certain conditions.

`BeanFactoryPostProcessor` provides a way to modify the bean definitions after Spring context is initialised which means that we can use it to configure which beans to be lazy programmatically .

All beans by default are not lazy. So if we want to configure all beans to be lazy in order to increase the Spring startup time , we have to manually annotate all beans with `@Lazy`.It is not so convenient if we have many beans. So what the articles mentioned is that in SpringBoot 2.2 will have a new feature to make all beans to be lazy by default such that so we don't need to manually annotate `@Lazy` for all beans. Behind the scene , it does it by registering this [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/aef92b9295f62d008faa9ab79905a474bf3496f3/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/LazyInitializationBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java) which simply do the followings:

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    for (String name : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(name);
        if (beanDefinition instanceof AbstractBeanDefinition) {
            Boolean lazyInit = ((AbstractBeanDefinition) beanDefinition).getLazyInit();
            if (lazyInit != null && !lazyInit) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        beanDefinition.setLazyInit(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` you can tweak about bean definition (NOT bean instance). One of the tweak is the `laziness` property:

```
public class MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

           beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("YourBeanName").setLazyInit(true);  
    }
}
```

It is equivalent to set `@Lazy` on the initialization of `YourBeanName` bean

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for your kind explanation.